# xamarin.form sqlite - how to query DataBase added to Assets folder

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

all. 
I managed to create and run Sqlite database in xamarin.forms, by create and run I mean when I run project I can add new elements to DB table.

Can I query this database from lets say SQLiteStudio? I tried and db table(in Assets folder) is empty, meanwhile when I run project, previously added elements are visible.

What should I do to query filled db table? Or what are the next steps to achive that?

Thanks for any tips.

Regards 
Michał

Comment: Assets (and anything bundled with the app) is read only.  You will need to create your db file in a writable folder if you want to do inserts/updates.

Comment: I'm able to insert new rows to table, but I would like to query db like lets say in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but you will need to copy the db file from the device/emulator to your local disk using adb

Comment: Its easier to create a view in your app which has access to the database file to have a Entry that take your query and run it.

Comment: Sooo, I tried to copy db from emulator to PC but I failed. How to use adb to copy db from emulator to PC? How to browse emulator 'hdd' to copy something from it? 
Should I implement copy db under the button?

Comment: Ok. I found the sollution for my issue.

1.Start your Emulator and make sure it's running.
2.Open up Visual Studio (if it's not open already).
3.Go to "Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor".

In your Devices Window Select your Emulator that is running. Then in the select the "File Explorer" tab and you should be able to browse your Emulator's file system.